# Permissions in Firebase notifications

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created this function in Google Cloud Platform associated with Firebase Realtime Database. The function sends a notification to mobile applications when something appears in the database.

As you can see below I set the priorities so that the notification will be noticed by the user

```
var message = {
    token: tokenSnapshot,
    notification: {
        title: "Title",
        body: "Body",
    },
    android: {
        priority: 'high',
        notification: {
            sound: 'default',
            priority: 'high',
            visibility: 'public'
        }
    },
};
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything. The notification comes but the user sees when he checks manually if something has come

I use a standard approach in the application

```
messaging().enable.setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
  })
```

**Is there any way for notifications to be with sound, vibration and to appear on the lock screen?**

I haven't used the `react-native-push-notification` library yet. Can this library help in this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firebase-cloud messaging i suggest using firebase in your app.
https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Make sure you follow the initial set up first.

Please read more about this here. https://rnfirebase.io/